GatherBy Question
In perusing this answer to a question about finding positions of duplicates, GatherBy is used in the following function:
positionDuplicates[list_] := GatherBy[Range@Length[list], list[[#]] &]

What I think I understand:
Range@Length[list] takes the input list and creates a list of integers starting at 1 up to the length of list, let's call this new list newList.
GatherBy applies the pure function list[[#]] & to each element of newList.
At this point, I am lost as to how it works because what the previous means to me is that what is done is something akin to
list[[1]]
list[[2]]
...
list[[Length[list]]]

which, if list were {10, 12, 10, 17, 18}, would yield
10
12
10
17
18
but, running the actual code yields:
{{1, 3}, {2}, {4}, {5}}

Which indicates I'm understanding very little!
I wrote a small function to dump out the arguments
myFunc[list_, index_] := Module[
   {},
   Print[
    StringForm["list: ``, index: ``, list[[index]]: ``", list, index, 
     list[[index]]]];
   list[[index]]
   ];

and modified positionDuplicates like so
positionDuplicates[list_] := 
 GatherBy[Range@Length[list], myFunc[list, #] &]

But, I still couldn't grok the mechanism by which it works.
Please help, thanks.

The first argument is Range[5] so the elements of {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} are going to be grouped based on matching parts of the list {10, 12, 10, 17, 18}. The first and third parts of list match; the second , fourth, and fifth parts of list do not match any other part of list.

Thanks @BobHanlon. Your response along with a-kato's was very helpful.

Let me explain by using the sample list in the cited question:
list = {3, 3, 6, 11, 13, 13, 11, 1, 2, 3, 12, 8, 9, 9, 4, 15, 5, 6, 9, 12};

positionDuplicates[list]
(* {{1, 2, 10}, {3, 18}, {4, 7}, {5, 6}, {8}, {9}, {11, 20}, {12}, {13, 14, 19}, {15}, {16}, {17}}

Let me call the first argument of GatherBy[Range@Length[list], list[[#]] &] as
A = Range@Length[list]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}*)

and when the function in the 2nd argument is mapped on A, the result is
B = list[[#]] & /@ A
(* {3, 3, 6, 11, 13, 13, 11, 1, 2, 3, 12, 8, 9, 9, 4, 15, 5, 6, 9, 12}*)

In fact, B is the same as list:
B === list
(* True *) 

Now, let us see what Gather do:
Gather[list]
(* {{3, 3, 3}, {6, 6}, {11, 11}, {13, 13}, {1}, {2}, {12, 12}, {8}, {9, 9, 9}, {4}, {15}, {5}} *)

The result can be depicted as

In fact, GatherBy[A, list[[#]] &] uses the same diagram because it arrange/group by the result of B = (list[[#]] &/@ A) = list. But, in contrast to Gather[list], this diagram is applied on A, not list itself.

I hope this explains why the original positionDuplicates (by @Szabolcs) works as expected.

Thanks so much @a-kato for the detailed breakdown.
So, would it be accurate to summarize what occurs in GatherBy as follows?


For each element in the first argument to GatherBy, f is evaluated and the resulting value is added to a collection of sorts.


Values that have already been matched get placed together in the same collection.


When all elements have been processed, the result is returned as a list of lists.



@a-kato, how did you generate the very cool arrow diagrams?

@anonmous I think your way of understanding it is correct.

G=Flatten[positionDuplicates[list]];F=Flatten[Gather[list]];diagram1=Graphics[Table[{Arrow[{{G[[i]],8},{i,0}}],Text[list[[i]],{i,9}],Text[F[[i]],{i,-1}]},{i,1,Length[list]}]];diagram2=Graphics[Table[{Arrow[{{G[[i]],8},{i,0}}],Text[A[[i]],{i,9}],Text[G[[i]],{i,-1}]},{i,1,Length[list]}]];

@a-kato, wow, I'm amazed that's Mathematica code!

Let me give another explanation from a different point of view. It's not one that will resonate with everyone perhap (so I'll add pretty picture to make up for it), but it might resonate with some who have worked in certain areas of mathematics or computer science.  In a comment to the answer, I said @Szabolcs's approach to my problem seemed natural. Not everyone agreed. So let me share why I thought that.
DeleteDuplicates[range] reduces the values in a list range to a set (no repeated entries).  In How to efficiently find positions of duplicates?, I was asking about position. {idx} = Position[range, value] is, with an exception, the inverse function of value = range[[idx]]. The exception is that Position[] can be multivalued (ignoring the structural difference that a position is a List[] of an index or indices and not the index itself). It would be more proper to speak of inverse relations here rather than of inverse functions, but I won't dwell on that technicality.
Now GatherBy[domain, f] in effect computes the inverse of f, throwing away the input values to f and returning the inverse images of f at each value in the range of f. This is what I asked for in the linked Q&A where the function f is Part[list, #]& and the domain is Range@Length[list] (and list is in effect the range of f referred to above).
Here's the pretty picture illustrating the relation being computed:
SeedRandom[1];
list = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 15]
(*  {2, 5, 1, 8, 1, 1, 9, 7, 1, 5, 2, 9, 6, 2, 2}  *)

f = Part[list, #] &; (* `list` serves as the `range` of f *)
domain = Range@Length@list;

GatherBy[domain, f]
(*  {{1, 11, 14, 15}, {2, 10}, {3, 5, 6, 9}, {4}, {7, 12}, {8}, {13}}  *)

ListPlot[Transpose[{domain, f /@ domain}], Filling -> Axis, 
 GridLines -> {None, list}]


A horizontal line intersect duplicates, when it intersects more than one point. The vertical lines from the points of intersection are points in the  domain with duplicate f values; and the points in the domain are by construction the Part indices of the duplicated values.
The first entry in the output of GatherBy[domain, f] is the set
{1, 11, 14, 15} which is inverse image of 2 under f (in math lingo) and might be written in math notation as $f^{-1}(\{2\}) = \{1, 11, 14, 15\}$. One can use Position[] to solve the problem, too, but it isn't efficient. (It's a good function to use if you just want one inverse image like Flatten@Position[list, 2].)
Inverse functions and relations are useful in solving some problems. Szabolcs's answer revealed this aspect of GatherBy[domain, f] to me, and I found it exciting to learn something new and useful. The newer GroupBy[domain, f] in effect computes the full inverse relation, since it gives an Association that maps each range value to its inverse image in the domain.

very clear and particularly with plot and useful to provide insight into how to learn from answers.

Yes, indeed ! (+1) Your words "GatherBy[domain, f] in effect computes the inverse of f" resonates with me.
